# ZF2 - render view from other action and module

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, zend-framework2

I have 2 modules (1 controller in it) in application in zend framework 2:
- news (with add, edit, get, list, and delete, .... shortList actions)
- application (with a few actions)

in news/get I would like to use outcome from shortList action (complete view) 
as well as in one of application module/controller.

more likely layout is not good place to do it - only 2 actions will reuse shortList content.
It seems like partial view or child view, however across modules.

How I should attempt to do it ?

Comment: Define it in config file of module and then use $this->render to add it in other action

Comment: could you expend this comment ? please and it looks like will work with same module only, isn't it

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

1. a view helper to read the data and render the view, so you can call it in any other view/layout 
   https://www.google.com/search?q=zf2+viewhelper&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=zf2+custom+viewhelper
2. `forward` to the other action and get its view model and add pass it to your current view as a var http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-forward